# How to find $\det(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$A$ be $3×3$ matrix whose characteristic roots are $3,2,-1$ and $B=A^{2}-A$ then how to find $\det(B)$.
Can anyone give me a clue? I know characteristic equation of $A$ is ${A^{3}-4A^{2}+A+6I=0}$ how to find characteristic equation of $B$ so that I can get its constant term which is $\det(B)$

Comment: Let $P(x)=\det(xI-A)$ the Characteristic polynomial of $A$ . As $B=(-A)(I-A)$ we have $\det(B)=\det(-A)\det(I-A)=P(0)P(1)$.

Comment: #kelenner as u mentioned $Det(B)=P(0)P(1)$ I got $P(0)=3×2×-1=-6$ now how to find $P(1)$

Comment: You have $P(x)=x^3-4x^2+x+6$ (you have computed the characteristic equation of $A$ in your question), ( or alternatively you have $P(x)=(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)$)

Comment: @kelenner I wrote eigen value at diagonal to form diagonal matrix and let it $A$ now I found $A-I$ as $2×1×-2=-4$ . am I right?

Comment: Thanx now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

$B = A(A-I)$, and you should be able to find $|A - I|$ by diagonalizing $A$.

Comment: can u explain bit more I can diagonalize $A$ then how to find $det(A-I)$ . I used a method first I wrote eigen value at diagonal to form diagonal matrix and let it $A$ now I found $A-I$ as $2×1×-2=-4$ . am I right?

Comment: @Ni TiSh write $A=PDP^{-1}$ and use the fact that $I = PP^{-1}$